# Where to find the complete debug log in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

When running my TypeScript Node app in Heroku, I get an error but there are no useful details. It says:
`A complete log of this run can be found in /app/.npm/_logs/2022-02-23T08_20_31_071Z-debug.log`

I tried `heroku logs --source app -t` but it's not showing the details, where can I find this `2022-....xxxx.log` file in Heroku so I can investigate the error?

Comment: You can't. The file system on the dyno is ephemeral, if your app crashed then the log file gets erased.

Comment: Are you getting that at _runtime_ or during deployment? During deployment there is usually a lot more information above that message explaining what happened.